# *EDITED*Alert dialog box only works on one instance (Android)

Tags: java, android

*edit*Sorry for the trouble, the reason for the bug was because I accidentally gave the findViewById(R.id.editTextemail2) to another edit text, which caused it to screw up.

I am trying to create a warning message to people who don't type in a proper email (no '.' or '@') and a second message to people who don't type the confirmation email exactly as the original. Can some one explain why my alert dialog only works for the first one and not the second one even though the code is nearly identical? The alert dialog is supposed to pop up once the person is done editing the text (leaves the edit text focus) Thanks!

```
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextemail);
email2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextemail2);
email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasFocus) {
    // checks if it is a proper email
    if (!hasFocus) {
        if (!hasPeriod(email.getText().toString())
                || !hasAt(email.getText().toString())) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAccount.this)
                    .setTitle("Error")
                    .setMessage(
        "Please enter a properly formatted email address to continue")
                    .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();

        }

    }
}
});

email2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasFocus) {
    // checks if it is a proper email
    if (!hasFocus) {
        if (!email.getText().toString()
                .contentEquals(email2.getText().toString())) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAccount.this)
                    .setTitle("Error")
                    .setMessage(
            "Please verify your email addresses match")
                .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();

        }

    }
}
});
```

Comment: What have you discovered from debugging? Does it make it inside the method at all? If so, at what point does it fail? Does it make it through the Alert Dialog code, but just never shows?

Comment: debugging in eclipse eventually brings me to a "source not found" page. So I just click resume and let the program do its thing. But from what I've seen it seems like it doesn't go into the second method.

Comment: I guess the obvious question is does `email2` ever lose focus? Can you perhaps put logging in your code to see if it ever makes it inside that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use equals instead of contentEquals

```
 if (!email.getText().toString().equals(email2.getText().toString())) {
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. It seems that my email2.setOnFOcusChangeListener doesn't get called at all which is weird.